# rotation Logic When Canvas Height and Width is Different

Tags: math, canvas, html5-canvas

need help to get canvas XY co oridantes when rotation is applied on canvas as pecially when size of canvas is different.

Comment: Please clarify your question :-) What do you mean by 'get canvas XY coordinates'? Notes: Keep in mind that context.rotate(angle) rotates the whole canvas coordinate system. If, after rotating and drawing, you haven't restored the canvas to it's default coordinate system, then any new draws will still be in rotated space so you can draw with unrotated coodinates and canvas will rotate for you. But...the browsers mouse handlers know nothing of the canvas rotation, so the mouse coordinates in the mouse handlers will be in unrotated coordinates even when the canvas is still rotated.

Comment: so how to map XY Co ordinates of mouse Event with my Canvas Current Rotation State ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that your question includes the 'math' tag but includes no code, so I'll give you a narrative mathematical solution.

**The problem**

As you've discovered, the browser's mouse events return clientX & clientY values in unrotated space rather than in rotated canvas coordinates.

**A potential solution**

To track the current rotation state of the canvas, you can use an **affine transformation matrix**. The affine matrix uses 6 of the 9 elements of a 3x3 matrix to hold accumulated information about all canvas transformations: *rotations, translations, scales, etc*. The matrix can be simply represented by an array of 6 elements.

```
var matrix=[ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ];
```

The canvas element keeps such a transformation matrix, but unfortunately (and unexpectedly) it's transformation matrix is hidden.

**An effective solution**

So alternatively, every time you issue a transformation command on the context, you can mirror that change to a transformation matrix you maintain yourself.  This way your matrix "saves" the current rotation state, no matter how many rotations,etc you do to the canvas.

Then when you get a mouse [x,y] defined in unrotated space, you can convert that unrotated mouse coordinate to rotated canvas space using that transformation matrix.

```
// convert mouse coordinates to transformed canvas coordinates
function tmPoint(matrix, mouseX, mouseY){
  return({
    canvasX: mouseX*matrix[0] + mouseY*matrix[2] + matrix[4],
    canvasY: mouseX*m[1] + mouseY*matrix[3] + matrix[5]
  };
}
```

**How-to...**

You can 'learn-up' on transformation matrices here:

https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/04/26/html5-canvas-games-tracking-transformation-matrices/